# What's the business model for being an anchor?

Tags: fees, business

we are looking at becoming an anchor for assets like BTC and ETH, but I don't understand what the business model would be for that. Do any of the current anchors for these assets charge any fees? For example, i looked at apay.io and there is no mention of fees or business model. How do companies that sponsor assets make money in general?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many(most?) anchors have withdrawal fees, including apay.io (https://apay.io/out).

Another possibility is working with other businesses and charging *them* a fee to use it - but this is probably more common with fiat anchors.